# Version control for same apps

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, multi-tenant, android-productflavors

I had created an android project for one of the grocery shops. Slowly, other grocery shops in my area also wanted the app. I created a few more similar app (on the same codebase architecture).
Now the problem with this is that if I need to rectify a bug or add a new feature in the app, I need to do the same replication in the other apps as well.
Right now, I've 8 apps and the version controlling is becoming a nightmare.

Any suggestions how should I go about it so that the maintenance and development is done only once?

PS: Code wise, all the apps are same having the change essentially in the app level build.gradle with a different name for `applicationId`.

Answer (score 3):

Solution to your problem is **Product Flavors**

> Creating product flavors is similar to creating build types: add them
>   to the productFlavors block and configure the settings you want. The
>   product flavors support the same properties as defaultConfig—this is
>   because defaultConfig actually belongs to the ProductFlavor class.
>   This means you can provide the base configuration for all flavors in
>   the defaultConfig block, and each flavor can change any of these
>   default values, such as the applicationId. To learn more about the
>   application ID, read Set the Application ID.

Please go through the official link for **[How to setup Product Flavors?](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors)**

Comment: also There is [MulitipleApk](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)